# Is it possible to specifically request users to upload an image using HTML5?

Tags: html, upload

Is it possible to specifically request users to upload an image using HTML5?

I know it is possible to upload a file using HTML5

```
<input type="file" />
```

and that you can check you can check the filetype using js or php

but can you make it so that you can only allow users to choose an image file like you do on an native program?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it using:

```
<input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*" />
```

The accept part can be changed like: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_accept.asp

Comment: Thumbs up to that very helpful and sourced with demo on W3schools.... I'm glad someone answered

Comment: btw can i use this upload on a <button> or even a normal styled div box?

Comment: I do not think that it's possible to do that unfortunately at least not just using HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this isn't supported by ie and safari.

Here is a possible solution as a jQuery plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Overview

Comment: true... are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Actually it does not work in older versions of Safari. I think it's since 5.2 or 5.3. At least it does work. You can look it up at: http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/07-accept.html

Comment: found a jQery plugin that can do it for you cross browser: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Overview

Comment: @Alex, I didn't check safari, but according to W3C it isn't supported - maybe W3C needs updating :) http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_accept.asp

Comment: Yes, sometimes even W3C does not have the most up to date information about brower compability. But it's still a very good source for learning.